# Use PCA to discover the most impactful variables on the original data set?

Tags: pca, feature-selection

I am trying to find a way to statistically show that some variables in my data set are more important than others to determine its classification. I have an example data set with three variables from 200 different WiFi boxes located in different buildings owned by a company.

- Variable A: Average speed of internet each user gets (Ex: Don't want the internet speed to be too low, which is about "3" or below, but for most people they won't notice much of a difference if the speed is above "5". )
- Variable B: Average count of how many users are using the WiFi throughout the day
- Variable C: Average percentage of resources used from the machine at that location

## The problem:

According to the company, all 200 routers are not providing good enough service to the users and must be replaced (Let's say replacing a 2.4 GHz WiFi router with a router that can do WiFi 5GHz). They say this because they are only looking at Variable_C and seeing that a large majority of the router's resources are being used (Let's say ~80%).

I argue that not all routers need to be replaced. What people care about is if their internet speed is high enough, not that the router is using a large amount of its resources. If a router is using 80%+ of its resources and still delivering 5+ internet speed, the router is fine and replacing it is a waste of money because most people wouldn't notice a speed increase larger than "5". **Is there a statistical method that I can use to show that Variable A&B are more important variables for classification because there are many examples where Variable A&B can vary wildly while Variable_C stays near constant 100%?**

## My steps to try to find a solution

To get a quick look at how my variables relate to each other, I created a pairplot in seaborn. From this I saw that some of my data is extremely skewed. Variable_A looks to be a decent normal distribution. Variable_B is extremely skewed and looks like a Poisson distribution. Variable_C is left skewed. 
[image]

I've read that when data is extremely skewed, it can be good to perform a natural log transformation to make the data approximately conform to normality. The new log transformed data pairplot looks like this. 
[image]
From this pairplot I can see some relationships between the variables. It seems that when the amount of users at a location increases, the user enjoyment decreases. I don't see any relationship between user enjoyment and percentage of resources used. I then created a pearson correlation matrix to get numerical values for each of the variables. 
[image]

The correlation plot solidifies what I saw from the log transformed pairplot. From here I am unsure how to proceed. I don't have a regression model I am trying to create because I have no response variable. All my data points have been pre-classified as "needing to be replaced". I just want to show that Variable_A and Variable_B are more important in determining whether something needs replaced instead of prioritizing Variable_C.

I presented my problem to a friend and he recommended I use Principal Component Analysis to get the most important features from the data. I studied math in school and learned briefly about the eigenvalues/eigenvectors of PCA, but I never really took any Statistics classes. The PCA examples I learned about were about facial recognition and cancer classifying using PCA and kmeans. I am trying to learn more everyday about different topics in statistics but I am moving slower than I'd like.

If PCA is the correct path for my problem, I have the following code which produces the chart and graph below:

```
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
import math

pca = PCA(n_components=2, svd_solver='full')
pca.fit(log_site_transform)

pca_site = pca.transform(log_site_transform)

pca.explained_variance_ratio_
components = pd.DataFrame(pca.components_, columns = list(log_site_transform.columns))



def get_important_features(transformed_features, components_, columns):
    """
    This function will return the most "important" 
    features so we can determine which have the most
    effect on multi-dimensional scaling
    """
    num_columns = len(columns)

    # Scale the principal components by the max value in
    # the transformed set belonging to that component
    xvector = components_[0] * max(transformed_features[:,0])
    yvector = components_[1] * max(transformed_features[:,1])

    # Sort each column by it's length. These are your *original*
    # columns, not the principal components.
    important_features = { columns[i] : math.sqrt(xvector[i]**2 + yvector[i]**2) for i in range(num_columns) }
    important_features = sorted(zip(important_features.values(), important_features.keys()), reverse=True)
    print("Features by importance:\n", important_features)

print(pca.explained_variance_ratio_)

print(get_important_features(pca_site, pca.components_, log_site_transform.columns.values))




def draw_vectors(transformed_features, components_, columns):
    """
    This funtion will project your *original* features
    onto your principal component feature-space, so that you can
    visualize how "important" each one was in the
    multi-dimensional scaling
    """

    num_columns = len(columns)

    # Scale the principal components by the max value in
    # the transformed set belonging to that component
    xvector = components_[0] * max(transformed_features[:,0])
    yvector = components_[1] * max(transformed_features[:,1])

    ax = plt.axes()

    for i in range(num_columns):
    # Use an arrow to project each original feature as a
    # labeled vector on your principal component axes
        plt.arrow(0, 0, xvector[i], yvector[i], color='b', width=0.0015, head_width=0.05, alpha=0.85)
        plt.text(xvector[i]*1.1, yvector[i]*1.1, list(columns)[i], color='k', alpha=0.75)

    return ax

plt.figure()
plt.style.use('seaborn-poster')
sns.set_palette('muted', color_codes=True); 
sns.set()
ax = draw_vectors(pca_site, pca.components_, log_site_transform.columns.values)
T_df = pd.DataFrame(pca_site)
T_df.columns = ['component1', 'component2']

T_df['color'] = 'b'
#T_df.loc[T_df['component1'] > 10, 'color'] = 'g'
#T_df.loc[T_df['component2'] > 10, 'color'] = 'r'

plt.xlabel('Principal Component #1')
plt.ylabel('Principal Component #2')
plt.xlim(-2, 3)

plt.scatter(T_df['component1'], T_df['component2'], color=T_df['color'], alpha=0.5)
```

## Can this be seen as a solution?

[image]
[image]

```
print(pca.explained_variance_ratio_)
log_site_transform.columns.values))
[0.73449626 0.24027837]

print(get_important_features(pca_site, pca.components_, 
Features by importance:
 [(2.18326388651478, 'Variable_B'), (1.850445828906843, 'Variable_A'), (0.3147679640995589, 'Variable_C_%')] None
```

I still need to read more in depth about PCA, but one goal of it is to show "the largest proportion of variance explained"? It seems to show that Variable A&B have the largest affects on the Principal Components and Variable_C has little. How do I translate the large effects on the principal components to how these variables affect the original data? 
Am I making this a lot more complicated than it needs to be to show that Variable_C should not be prioritized as a key identifier for optimal performance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PCA uses orthogonal transformation to generate new features on the directions that maximize the data variance, so it does not reveal the importance of the original features. Instead of PCA, random forest can be used to study the feature importance. The example using sklearn is presented [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/ensemble/plot_forest_importances.html).

Comment: The example you linked from sklearn seems to relate well to my problem. I will read more about random forests.

Comment: @hoobs52 Then you may be interested in the Boruta algorithm, which attempts to obtain all relevant features of a problem for some task (e.g. classification). Boruta does this by applying successive rounds of an ensemble classifier such as Random Forest.

Answer (score 0):

PCA creates a new set of coordinates (the components) that explains most of the variance. It does feature engineering, not feature selection. You can use it undirectly to do the task, but it's more work than required.

If you want to do proper feature selection, start with one of the tools in scikit-learn that do [feature selection](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/feature_selection.html). One of these algorithms should easily give you the 2 variables that explain your data out of three.